# Loop through a combination from an answer key

Tags: c#, .net, list, for-loop

From a random stats from `statsList`, I wanted to get the right combination of stats for this game but I was only able to get what I want by manually checking for each one. Is there a more efficient way to loop the given strings with a set of answer keys?
Like - *if stats is one of the X number of answerKeys then correct* (loop through the 4 of them, with priority if possible)

Here's what I did at the moment -

```
var stat1 = statsList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains("stamina"));
var stat2 = statsList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains("agility"));
var stat3 = statsList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains("dodge")); 
var stat4 = statsList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains("max hp") || s.Contains("defense"));

if (stat1 != null && stat2 != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(stat3) && stat4 != null)
     // do something
```

So basically, every time I check the `statsList` it needs to have the 4 I have chosen, like the one above. This code checks the loop if it has the stat I am looking for. It does the job, but I wonder if there is a better way. So that I can just let's say - `LookUpForStats(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5 ..)`

Comment: I don't think I can follow what the exact requirement is. As-Is, all of the "keys" need to be present. Now, what exactly do you want instead?

Comment: This is the same as the text filter: checking if a word is a bad word. So you can build a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for the given strings.

Comment: @Fildor I updated the question. Yes I have the keys, so I wanted to look at the given list if its present or not. Just looking for a better way how to loop through it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
wantedStats = new List<string>{"stamina", "agility", "dodge"};
noneIsNull = true;

foreach(string name in wantedStats){
  stats = statsList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains(name));
  if (stats == null){
    noneIsNull = false;
    break;
  }
}
if (noneIsNull)
  // Do Something
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**